# splitting multi-line email address entries

Tags: php, arrays

I'm having problems with splitting an array correctly. I have a textarea input that allows for multiple email addresses to be entered one per line.  Once entered I'm turning this into an array and then adding them to a database. Code below:

`$addrs = explode('<br />',nl2br($form['bulk_add_emails']));`

This is still leaving a linebreak in the database entry before the email address, which means when I run a validation check using

`if(preg_match('/^([a-zA-Z0-9])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-])*@([a-zA-Z0-9_-])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+)+$/', $v)){ ... }`

everything is returning as false.

What am I doing wrong and how can I clean up the data correctly?

Comment: Why exactly don't you simply explode on `\n` instead of doing this horribly sin with `nl2br`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't `explode()` on `<br />` and don't call `nl2br()`.  Instead, use [`preg_split()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) for more flexibility in processing the linebreaks, which can handle multiple lines if there's an empty line, and `\r\n` or `\n` linebreaks.

```
// (\r?\n)+ will split on one or more \n with an optional \r preceding it.
// ... so empty lines don't result in empty array elements.
$addrs = preg_split('/(\r?\n)+/', $form['bulk_add_emails']);
```

Comment: I've always struggled with regular expressions. worked like a charm. thanks for the help!